# DIY check for browser support for TSL1.1 protocol?

Tags: encryption, browser, feature-detection

I'm going to include GestPay Payment in my website. It has some [browser requirements](http://docs.gestpay.it/sec/software-requirements.html)

> Buyer’s browsers must support TSL1.1 protocol or latest

How can I programmatically check if the browser visiting my website achieves the requirement?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991911/detect-browser-tls-compatibility) the suggestion is to use external services *(ssllabs.com, howsmyssl.com)*, but I want a self hosted solution, without external dependencies, the main reason for this are security concerns.

In [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enabling-TLS-1-1-and-TLS-1-2-in-Internet-Explorer&type=1) salesforce.com exposes a [test page](https://tls1test.salesforce.com/s/), with Chrome Dev Tools, I've tried to disable javascript and the test works the same. So I suppose that is server-side...

**Update:**

Ideally I would like to allow browsers even without TSL1.1 support, then detect if the browser supports TSL1.1, if it doesn't I won't show the GestPay Payment feature.

Comment: Looks like a server configuration question rather than a programming question. You need to configure your server to only accept TLS 1.1 or greater, and you should probably configure it to accept TLS 1.2 or greater.

Comment: Thanks James, I updated my question, I hope is more clear now.

Comment: Isn't this still a server configuration question?

Comment: Hi, one of the solutions that you posted (How's my ssl) can actually be installed on your webserver autonomously, so that the check can be made to a page that is self hosted.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a while, this is what I understood:

In this caniuse table are listest [browsers not supporting tls1.1](http://caniuse.com/#feat=tls1-1)

When a browser asks an https page, it sends the list of supported encryption protocols, the server choose the best one.

If the server doesn't allow a protocol lesser than TLS1.1, the browser won't see the page at all, for example this is IE9 behavior:
[image: IE9 behavior for un]

In [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript) there is no access to https certificate info.

There is no way to do a feature detection about this.

In the [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) the info is not available, neither in the [PHP $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal.

So you could run by your own the [opensource HowsMySsl server](https://github.com/jmhodges/howsmyssl) (but to me is too overkill)

So maybe I will go with user-agent sniffing to determine if the browser is not supporting TLS1.1, even if [user-agent sniffing is bad](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/)

I hope that this will help someone else out there!